# Where can I find keyboard key combinations that enter non-printable terminal characters?

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, ncurses

For example, in my xterm to get:

`000`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> **or** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>

`001`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

`002`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

`003`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

`004`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

`005`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

`006`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

`007`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

`008`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

`009`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> **or** <kbd>Tab</kbd>

`010`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> **or** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> **or** <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`011`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

`012`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

`013`: can't find any.

`014`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

`015`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

`016`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

`017`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

`018`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

`019`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

`020`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

`021`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

`022`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

`023`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

`024`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

`025`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

`026`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

`027`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> **or** <kbd>Esc</kbd>

`028`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

`029`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

`030`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>

`031`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> **or** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Characters from `032` to `127`, inclusively, are all printable, but there are some that can be referred in multiple ways using either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> or a combination of those.

Then there are characters from `128` to something I don't know.

---

Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import curses
import os


def main(stdscr):
    curses.raw()
    while True:
        stdscr.addstr(0, 0, str(stdscr.getch()))
        stdscr.refresh()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault('ESCDELAY', '0')
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: AFAIK, in Xterm (or any decent terminal emulator) <U+000D> is `^M` (Control-M) or <Enter>. You don't have to set any environment variable to make <Esc> or `^[` produce <U+001B>. To test, start `vim`, enter insert mode (`i`) and press `^V` <Esc>; you will get an <U+001B> instantly. Also, you can extend your table to <U+001F>: `^\ `, `^]`, `^^`, `^_` (that is, control-`\ `, control-`]`, control-`^` and control-`_`). This has been so since the beginning of time, when terminals where real pieces of hardware.